# LDA topic models for various and unknown domains

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, topic-models

We have a large collection (1-2M) of documents of various domains (politics, design, programming, etc.). And lets assume that we don't know the exact number of domains. And our goal is to build relevant topic models for these domains. For example I want to find *N* topics in each domain. For politics it could be: foreign policy, government, economic policy, etc. For design domain: web design, architecture, etc. And so on.
If I understand correctly, when using a [LDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation) it is necessary to form a training set for specified domain (e.g. politics). But problem arises if there is no information about domain. How can I form a training set in that case? I was thinking about building index, extracting documents, that contain significant words (defined by [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf-idf)). But it seems that it is not the best solution.
If instead of LDA we can use [HDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_Dirichlet_process) and handle training set compiled with random documents. But there arises another problem - a huge vocabulary, which may not fit in the memory (we need much more words to describe several domains, than one).
So the problem is: what is the best way to build topic models (or one topic model?) of various (and unknown) domains? And them apply this models to new (unseen) documents.

Comment: Please unfold abbreviations "LDA", "TF-IDF", "HDP" in yout question. Not everybody knows these acronyms.

Comment: @ttnphns, I've added links to wikipedia.

Comment: @peppered what did you end up doing for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hierarchical topic models are designed precisely for this task. These models infer topic hierarchies where high level topics (poltics, sports) have subtopics beneath them (foreign policy, baseball).

The original formulation is from this paper

- [Hierarchical Topic Models and
  the Nested Chinese Restaurant Process](http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips16/NIPS2003_AA03.pdf)

And this very recent formulation, which is able to infer more accurate hierarchical structures

- [Nested Hierarchical Dirichlet Processes](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.6738.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how can I form a training set (from a huge collection), which would cover all domains? Or it supposed to use all (about 2 millions) documents in original collection?

Comment: Yes, the idea is that it will discover the tree structure on it's own from the entire document collection.

Comment: If I understand correctly for big collections it should be used an online version of hLDA (or nHDP)?

Comment: @pepper, I don't think that's the case. What makes you think that? On-line inference is generally more difficult than batch processing because of the constraints on computing time.

Comment: I'm new in this area, so it was my supposition. If to be honest, I did not think that there is a big difference between online and batch processing.

Comment: Is there any way to apply hierarchical models to unseen documents?

Comment: @pepper, sure. You first perform inference on the data you have then if you get new documents you can use the parameter values you inferred on the training set to make an inference about new items.

Comment: for better understanding I have another question. What is the difference between hLDA and using LDA "recursively". Under the latest I understand, that we can use LDA to discover basic topics from whole corpus, and then use LDA on already discovered topics and open new topics within "parent" topic. And repeat this process recursively into some levels deep (like in hLDA). Or it is a bad idea?

Comment: @Pepper: Yes, you could also fit topic models recursively as you say. That may or may not be more computationally tractable, I'm not sure, but I suspect the resulting topic hierarchies would be considerably inferior in quality. Inferring the hierarchy all at once, as with hLDA (or nHDPs), will provide the optimal global structure, whereas recursively fitting LDA models to construct a tree would be locally optimal, a sort of [greedy algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm). I'm not expert however, so if this point is important you might make it a new question.